# Mysql how to reduce rows by max datetime and group by non-uniqe id

Tags: mysql, datetime, join, group-by

I am having a severe case of brain flatulence.

Keeping it simple, I have 3 tables:  **Orders**, **Statuses**, **XrefOrdersStatuses**

I've setup an SQLFiddle ([SQLFiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ae7c/9)) with simplified schema and some redacted row data.

What I need to get are Orders with their most recent XrefOrdersStatuses (joined with Statuses).  I can sort of do this using the following query:

```
SELECT o.shopper_name_first, o.shopper_name_last, os.os_name, x.xos_order_id, x.xos_status_id, x.xos_datetime
FROM Orders AS o 
INNER JOIN XrefOrdersStatuses AS x ON x.xos_order_id = o.order_id
LEFT JOIN Statuses AS os ON os.os_id = x.xos_status_id
ORDER BY x.xos_order_id, x.xos_datetime DESC
```

The result looks like:

```
| shopper_name_first | shopper_name_last |             os_name | xos_order_id | xos_status_id |           xos_datetime |
|--------------------|-------------------|---------------------|--------------|---------------|------------------------|
|              Sally |               Sue | Order Pre-Processed |        34049 |            31 | June, 18 2015 12:42:50 |
|              Sally |               Sue |          Order Paid |        34049 |            20 | June, 18 2015 12:36:30 |
|              Sally |               Sue |       Order Created |        34049 |            10 | June, 18 2015 12:34:56 |
|                Joe |            Schmoe | Order Pre-Processed |        34050 |            31 | June, 18 2015 12:54:50 |
|                Joe |            Schmoe |          Order Paid |        34050 |            20 | June, 18 2015 12:38:30 |
|                Joe |            Schmoe |       Order Created |        34050 |            10 | June, 18 2015 12:34:56 |
|              Peter |             Piper |          Order Paid |        34051 |            20 | June, 18 2015 12:37:30 |
|              Peter |             Piper |       Order Created |        34051 |            10 | June, 18 2015 12:34:56 |
```

In the production scenario I am *SELECT*(ing) more/all of the Orders table columns, just left them out here for simplicity. Note the duplicate orders, but the statuses line up.

In the view I'm working on the purpose is NOT to find the most recent statuses.  This view lists orders, and I want to join/match each order with its respective most recent status based on the maximum datetime column value.  A one-to-many schema (one order with many statuses).

So what I want to do is:

- SELECT order
- JOIN xref with MAX(xos_datetime) GROUP BY xos_order_id
- JOIN statuses to get definitions

Orders must remain the left side table in the query (for other joins used with other tables). After going through many other SO questions and answers and many Google searches I have not quite found what I need.

If needed to get JUST the XrefOrdersStatuses by max datetime and grouped by order id, this would be the query....

```
SELECT x.*
FROM XrefOrdersStatuses AS x
JOIN (
  SELECT xos_order_id, MAX(xos_datetime) AS maxdate
  FROM XrefOrdersStatuses
  GROUP BY xos_order_id
  ) AS x1 ON x1.xos_order_id = x.xos_order_id AND x1.maxdate = x.xos_datetime;
```

Resulting in:

```
| xos_id | xos_order_id | xos_status_id |           xos_datetime |
|--------|--------------|---------------|------------------------|
| 118287 |        34051 |            20 | June, 18 2015 12:37:30 |
| 118289 |        34049 |            31 | June, 18 2015 12:42:50 |
| 118290 |        34050 |            31 | June, 18 2015 12:54:50 |
```

... yay!  The most recent status for each order!

Alas, I need the Orders table to be the left side table (other joins and where searches -- i.e. name, active/inactive, assigned to user, etc).

My trouble is combining the Orders query with the XrefOrdersStatuses query.  I just cannot quite seem to get them to play together.  My attempts fail with ordering, and grouping, and all sorts of heated messes.

I feel like this gets me close, but getting the grouping and ordering correct is where I'm flatulating:

```
SELECT o.shopper_name_first, o.shopper_name_last, os.os_name, x.xos_order_id, x.xos_status_id, x.xos_datetime
FROM Orders AS o 
JOIN (
  SELECT xz.*
  FROM XrefOrdersStatuses AS xz
  JOIN (
    SELECT xos_order_id, MAX(xos_datetime) AS maxdate
    FROM XrefOrdersStatuses
    GROUP BY xos_order_id
  ) AS x1 ON x1.xos_order_id = xz.xos_order_id AND x1.maxdate = xz.xos_datetime
) AS x
LEFT JOIN Statuses AS os ON os.os_id = x.xos_status_id
ORDER BY x.xos_order_id, x.xos_datetime DESC;
```

Result looks like this:

```
| shopper_name_first | shopper_name_last |             os_name | xos_order_id | xos_status_id |           xos_datetime |
|--------------------|-------------------|---------------------|--------------|---------------|------------------------|
|                Joe |            Schmoe | Order Pre-Processed |        34049 |            31 | June, 18 2015 12:42:50 |
|              Peter |             Piper | Order Pre-Processed |        34049 |            31 | June, 18 2015 12:42:50 |
|              Sally |               Sue | Order Pre-Processed |        34049 |            31 | June, 18 2015 12:42:50 |
|                Joe |            Schmoe | Order Pre-Processed |        34050 |            31 | June, 18 2015 12:54:50 |
|              Peter |             Piper | Order Pre-Processed |        34050 |            31 | June, 18 2015 12:54:50 |
|              Sally |               Sue | Order Pre-Processed |        34050 |            31 | June, 18 2015 12:54:50 |
|              Peter |             Piper |          Order Paid |        34051 |            20 | June, 18 2015 12:37:30 |
|              Sally |               Sue |          Order Paid |        34051 |            20 | June, 18 2015 12:37:30 |
|                Joe |            Schmoe |          Order Paid |        34051 |            20 | June, 18 2015 12:37:30 |
```

I tried different variations, tried working forward, backward, left, right, in, out, up, down, hot, cold, wet, dry... you get the picture.

What I need is for it to look like this:

```
| shopper_name_first | shopper_name_last |             os_name | xos_order_id | xos_status_id |           xos_datetime |
|--------------------|-------------------|---------------------|--------------|---------------|------------------------|
|              Sally |               Sue | Order Pre-Processed |        34049 |            31 | June, 18 2015 12:42:50 |
|                Joe |            Schmoe | Order Pre-Processed |        34050 |            31 | June, 18 2015 12:54:50 |
|              Peter |             Piper |          Order Paid |        34051 |            20 | June, 18 2015 12:37:30 |
```

If you go back to the first query ... I need those results, but reduced so that only the most recent status for each order remains.  I'm actually doing this after the fact in PHP ... hence I am revisiting the query to remove that seemingly unnecessary step from PHP.

Perhaps my solution would be the XrefOrdersStatuses query (second one above) but use RIGHT JOIN to grab the Order and Status tables?

Thoughts anyone? Sorry for making this so long (almost TL;DR for myself), but I'm hoping I've annotated the question appropriately.

BTW -- I'm a longtime lurker of SO (innumerable questions and tips have been gleaned from questions found on here!) but this is the first time that I've gotten stuck and been unable to figure out how to get what I need.

---

EDIT/ANSWER:  Got the query setup the way I need, and discovered my performance problems were column and indexing related.  Kind of like going to the hospital for abdominal pain, only to be told you have Crohns, then discover you have a tumor on the kidney -- and things turn out good in the end.

```
# Query for answer to user Linoff with mods
SELECT o.shopper_name_first, o.shopper_name_last, s.os_name, x.*
FROM Orders o 
RIGHT JOIN XrefOrdersStatuses x ON x.xos_order_id = o.order_id 
RIGHT JOIN
(
  SELECT xos_order_id, MAX(xos_datetime) AS maxdate
  FROM XrefOrdersStatuses
  GROUP BY xos_order_id
) xmax ON xmax.xos_order_id = x.xos_order_id AND xmax.maxdate = x.xos_datetime
LEFT JOIN Statuses s ON s.os_id = x.xos_status_id
ORDER BY o.order_datetime DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT <choose your columns here>
FROM Orders o LEFT JOIN
     XrefOrdersStatuses x
     ON x.xos_order_id = o.order_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT xos_order_id, MAX(xos_datetime) AS maxdate
      FROM XrefOrdersStatuses
      GROUP BY xos_order_id
     ) xmax
     ON xmax.xos_order_id = x.xos_order_id AND
        xmax.maxdate = x.xos_datetime;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is only necessary if you have orders with no status records.

Comment: It works, and it doesn't work.... I've tried this route several different ways. Though, building off someone going down the same path and thinking back to RIGHT JOINs instead...

An answer may be at hand.  Testing in the IDE....

Comment: If we modify to RIGHT JOIN for the Xref joins, LEFT JOIN to the Statuses, and ORDER BY Orders.order_datetime it seems to work in the fiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ae7cc/4/0

But when I replicate in my console I cannot get similar output on production data.  I'm getting very poor performance on the query.  I'm beginning to wonder if my goal of getting the query to serve the data I need is best.

Comment: @Rodney .  . . If you have proper foreign key relationships, I don't see why you would need to mix left and right joins.  In fact, other than the possibility that some orders may have no status, you shouldn't need outer joins at all.

Comment: I'm not using foreign keys in this database because it isn't supported with the MyISAM engine and I use full-text searching with frequent simple select queries on most tables.  Though, it may be time to look at changing to InnoDB where possible (db schema hasn't been revisited since 2011).

In my dev server I can run the basic query very similar to what you posted (with my desired columns), but I get results with oldest datetime at the front of the set.  Different from what the SQLFiddle outputs.  

I'm trying to reconcile the cause.

Comment: @Rodney . . . This assumes that the datetime value is stored properly in a `datetime` column.  If you are storing it as a string, then you are just getting the maximum value of the string.  Once again, you should fix your data.

Comment: Perhaps I should note that on dev database I'm building from the Orders table has 18k rows, and the XrefOrdersStatuses table has 54k rows. The same tables exist in multiple company databases with varying numbers of rows.

Comment: I just checked and the Xref table is using "timestamp" as the column type, when I use "datetime" everywhere else.  I think that may be legacy from when the code did inserts without the datetime explicitly set in the insert (guessing because the default is set to "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP").

Comment: Marked as question answered.  Changed the column type to datetime and adjusted the table indexes -- query with crazy joins runs as expected without performance hits from ordering and where clauses.  Already located the two insert objects for that table and updated them to explicitly set the `xos_datetime` field.  ;-)